# C# delegate Invalidcast Exception

Tags: c#, delegates

I am stuck with an InvalidCast Exception. I am calling a delegate to run some function. In the callback method of the delegate I am trying to get the return value of the function as shown below.

```
     public delegate SyncHelper.SyncPlan RunJobDelegate();

     public static void SyncJobCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {

        RunJobDelegate runSyncJob = (RunJobDelegate)result.AsyncState;
        SyncHelper.SyncPlan obj_Plan = runSyncJob.EndInvoke(result);
```

When RunJobDelegate runSyncJob = (RunJobDelegate)result.AsyncState; is called I am hitting an exception saying "Unable to cast object of type 'RunJobDelegate' to type 'RunJobDelegate'. "

Please help me with the solution if anyone has seen this before.

Divya.

Comment: Could you post the `BeginInvoke` code too?

Comment: Can you show more of the code? Specifically, how is the RunJobDelegate being initialized and started?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895163/invalidcastexception-casting-object-to-its-own-type/3895578#3895578

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing should only ocurr if you have two different RunJobDelegate types defined in your code.  Make sure it isn't defined twice.

If that isn't the problem, please most more of the code (including the calling function) for us to examine.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I have declared the same type of delegate but in a different namespace in a different class. I have removed that and used the already existing one and my issue got resolved. But can you please tell me why that is an issue?

Comment: System.Data.Whatever is a totally different type than Your.Own.Namespace.Whatever.  Having the same "last name" doesn't make them the same type.  So, if you used the first type and tried to cast it to the second type, it would fail without a way to convert one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the type of result.AsyncState in the debugger?

also are you sure you want to use AsyncState and not AsyncDelegate?

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.asyncstate.aspx